# Is an ELF SHT_RELA section with a 0 `sh_link` valid?

Tags: elf

I have an 64-bit s390x ELF binary with a RELA section named ".rela.plt" whose `sh_link` field is 0. I was under the impression that the `sh_link` is a required value, providing the id of the section where the symbols used by the relocations are stored.

If I run `objdump` on the binary no information about any relocations is emitted, hinting that perhaps there are no relocations to be done. The following is repored by `readelf`:

```
There are 36 section headers, starting at offset 0xa91c8:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             0000000080000190  00000190
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 2] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE             00000000800001b0  000001b0
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .rela.plt         RELA             00000000800001d8  000001d8
       0000000000000018  0000000000000018  AI       0    23     8
  [ 4] .init             PROGBITS         00000000800001f0  000001f0
       000000000000004c  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [ 5] .plt              PROGBITS         000000008000023c  0000023c
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [ 6] .text             PROGBITS         0000000080000260  00000260
       000000000006c328  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [ 7] __libc_freeres_fn PROGBITS         000000008006c588  0006c588
       0000000000000f18  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     8
  [ 8] __libc_thread_fre PROGBITS         000000008006d4a0  0006d4a0
       00000000000000f0  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     8
  [ 9] .fini             PROGBITS         000000008006d590  0006d590
       0000000000000034  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [10] .rodata           PROGBITS         000000008006d5c8  0006d5c8
       000000000001d810  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [11] __libc_subfreeres PROGBITS         000000008008add8  0008add8
       0000000000000058  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [12] __libc_atexit     PROGBITS         000000008008ae30  0008ae30
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [13] __libc_thread_sub PROGBITS         000000008008ae38  0008ae38
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [14] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         000000008008ae40  0008ae40
       000000000000aa2c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [15] .gcc_except_table PROGBITS         000000008009586c  0009586c
       00000000000000c5  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [16] .tdata            PROGBITS         0000000080096ed0  00095ed0
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     8
  [17] .tbss             NOBITS           0000000080096ef0  00095ef0
       0000000000000034  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     8
  [18] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       0000000080096ef0  00095ef0
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [19] .ctors            PROGBITS         0000000080096ef8  00095ef8
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [20] .dtors            PROGBITS         0000000080096f08  00095f08
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .jcr              PROGBITS         0000000080096f18  00095f18
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [22] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS         0000000080096f20  00095f20
       00000000000000e0  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .got              PROGBITS         0000000080097000  00096000
       00000000000000c8  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [24] .data             PROGBITS         00000000800970c8  000960c8
       00000000000019c8  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [25] .bss              NOBITS           0000000080098a90  00097a90
       0000000000002070  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [26] __libc_freeres_pt NOBITS           000000008009ab00  00097a90
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [27] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00097a90
       0000000000000034  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [28] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00097ac4
       0000000000000030  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [29] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00097af4
       00000000000000ed  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [30] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00097be1
       000000000000007f  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [31] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00097c60
       000000000000004c  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [32] .debug_str        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00097cac
       00000000000000d3  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [33] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  000a903e
       0000000000000186  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [34] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00097d80
       000000000000ae00  0000000000000018          35   759     8
  [35] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  000a2b80
       00000000000064be  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)
```

In addition, on stderr I see:

```
readelf: Warning: [ 3]: Link field (0) should index a symtab section.
```

Should I be interpreting the zero `sh_link` for the ".rela.plt" section as a hint that there is no work to be done?

Comment: can you paste the output of `readelf -S`?

Comment: Here's the paste: https://pastebin.com/BJ34L5aL  readelf is complaining about the RELA section too. The binary is here: https://github.com/angr/binaries/blob/master/tests/s390x/test-instr_s390x

Comment: Better add it to the question

Comment: It could ofc be a linker bug, but it seems so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

On the surface it seems indeed that this file does not conform to the ELF specification.

I will need to look at the file but I expect it does have relocations and you should not skip them. It seems the flags have `SHF_INFO_LINK` set which means the index should be looked up in the `sh_info` field and  23 points to the `.got` section which means relocations apply to it.

One possibility is that relocations do not use symbols (e.g. only `IRELATIVE` type relocations) and another is that it uses the only `SYMTAB` present in the file (index 34).

**EDIT**: it seems my theory was correct. Output of `readelf -r`:

```
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x1d8 contains 1 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000080097018  00000000003d R_390_IRELATIVE                      800174b0
```

The `*_IRELATIVE` relocations do not refer to a symbol and thus do not need a symbol table.